# Determine which button was clicked when two buttons are on a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to add two buttons in my form to capture time when vendor is contacted and when they reply.

The Problem I am having is that when I click one button the value is changing in both fields. Please advice how I can fix this.

Thank you!

```
 <tr>     
    <th>
    <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
      <button name="start" >Start</button><br>
      <?php
      session_start ();
      if (isset($_POST['start']))
      {
      $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
      }
      ?>
      <br>
      <input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>"
      <br>
      </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <th>
      <p>Vendor responded at:</p>
      <button name="response" >Response</button><br>
      <?php
      if (isset($_POST['response']))
      {
      $date_response = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['response'] = $date_response;
      }
      ?>
      <br>
      <input name="response" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['response']; ?>"
      <br>
      </th>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Have to written something on button click?

Comment: Because both buttons are in same form. If you submit by any of button, it'll change both fields values.. So you need to divide it to two forms, having one text field, one button in each!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are suggesting that I should have two form one button for each form such as:
<form1>
      button code
</form1>
<form2>
    button code
<form2>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here...

First - you are loading the page and trying to echo a session that doesn't exist. This will give you errors.

To fix this, place `$_SESSION['start'] = '';` just above `if (isset($_POST['start']))` AND place `$_SESSION['response'] = '';` just above `if (isset($_POST['response']))` This defines your sessions, but with an empty value.

Second - Place each of your Table rows in their own table and form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table>
  <tr>     
    <th>
    <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
      <button name="start" >Start</button><br>
      <?php
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
          session_start ();
      }
      /* these five lines ask if there is an existing session & if there is an existing session... is it empty
      if there is an existing session & it's not empty... we use it
      otherwise... we create an empty session to prevent errors
      this also maintains the session data when the other button is clicked like you asked in your comments */
      if(isset($_SESSION['start']) && $_SESSION['start'] != '') {
          $_SESSION['start'] = $_SESSION['start'];
      } else {
          $_SESSION['start'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['start']))
      {
      $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
      }
      ?>
      <br>
      <input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>">
      <br>
      </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="">
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>
      <p>Vendor responded at:</p>
      <button name="response" >Response</button><br>
      <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['response']) && $_SESSION['response'] != '') {
          $_SESSION['response'] = $_SESSION['response'];
      } else {
          $_SESSION['response'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['response']))
      {
      $date_response = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['response'] = $date_response;
      }
      ?>
      <br>
      <input name="response" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['response']; ?>">
      <br>
      </th>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Update:**

If you want to retain the data (if you want your data to persist)... change ...

```
      <?php
      session_start ();
      $_SESSION['start'] = '';
      if (isset($_POST['start'])) {
          $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
          $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
      }
      ?>
```

to...

```
      <?php
      if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
          session_start ();
      }
      if(isset($_SESSION['start']) && $_SESSION['start'] != '') {
          $_SESSION['start'] = $_SESSION['start'];
      } else {
          $_SESSION['start'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['start']))
      {
      $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
      }
      ?>
```

and change...

```
  <?php
  $_SESSION['response'] = ''; 
  if (isset($_POST['response'])) {
      $date_response = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['response'] = $date_response;
  }
  ?>
```

to...

```
      <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['response']) && $_SESSION['response'] != '') {
          $_SESSION['response'] = $_SESSION['response'];
      } else {
          $_SESSION['response'] = '';
      }
      if (isset($_POST['response']))
      {
      $date_response = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
      $_SESSION['response'] = $date_response;
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: @TomKriek - The reason clicking either of the buttons changes both text fields is because they are both in the same form. They have to be separated into separate forms as indicated in my answer. You might want to take a closer look and reconsider.

Comment: @Kuya - Thank you for your suggestion. I made the changes you suggested and created a two forms with code. However, when I click on one button the other button data gets cleared. Please advice.

Comment: Still same issue. When I hit start it is updating response as well and vise versa.

Comment: Please look at your code carefully and compare it to what I have written above. If you have separated your forms as in the asnwer, and paid close attention to naming elements, `start` will not update `response` and vice versa. The code above has been tested and functions as you want it to.

Comment: Also try doing a "hard" refresh using Ctrl-f5 to make sure you're not pulling a cached page

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I separated the form to different files and it is working now. However, I am not able to see the echo of time in IE, but it works in Firefox and chrome. Any advice?

Comment: What version of IE are you using? I tested using IE 11.0.9600.17905 and everything is ok.

Comment: Mine is IE8. Not sure why it is not displaying. But when I hit submit I see the time in it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You say it's not displaying, but then you say you can see the time in it (the text box). IE has always been a pain for programmers. Sigh. I might have an old computer with IE 8 on it. I'll look around and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$_POST['start']` is a value of input named `start` and `$_POST['response']` is a value of input named `response`.
If you want to know which button was clicked in form you have to set a value to a button. Change `<button name="start" >` into `<input type="submit" value="start" />`. Than check a button clicked like this `if ('start' === $_POST['submit'])`.
To the bottom, your code should look like this:

```
<tr>     
    <th>
        <p>Vendor was contacted at:</p>
          <!-- changed line -->
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="start" /><br>
          <?php
          session_start ();
          /* changed line */
          if ('start' === $_POST['submit']) {
              $date_start = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
              $_SESSION['start'] = $date_start;
          }
          ?>
          <br>
          <input name="start" type="text" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['start']; ?>"
          <br>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for replying. Now I don't see the date in the text field when I hit the start button. The form gets refreshed.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. Button should have a name also!
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="start" />`